# How to normalize a 2-dimensional numpy array in python less verbose?

Tags: python, arrays, syntax, numpy, normalization

Given a 3 times 3 numpy array

```
a = numpy.arange(0,27,3).reshape(3,3)

# array([[ 0,  3,  6],
#        [ 9, 12, 15],
#        [18, 21, 24]])
```

To normalize the rows of the 2-dimensional array I thought of

```
row_sums = a.sum(axis=1) # array([ 9, 36, 63])
new_matrix = numpy.zeros((3,3))
for i, (row, row_sum) in enumerate(zip(a, row_sums)):
    new_matrix[i,:] = row / row_sum
```

There must be a better way, isn't there?

Perhaps to clearify: By normalizing I mean, the sum of the entrys per row must be one. But I think that will be clear to most people.

Comment: Careful, "normalize" usually means the *square* sum of components is one. Your definition will hardly be clear to most people;)

Comment: @coldfix speaks about `L2` norm and considers it as most common (which may be true) while Aufwind uses `L1` norm which is also a norm indeed.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Broadcasting is really good for this:

```
row_sums = a.sum(axis=1)
new_matrix = a / row_sums[:, numpy.newaxis]
```

`row_sums[:, numpy.newaxis]` reshapes row_sums from being `(3,)` to being `(3, 1)`. When you do `a / b`, `a` and `b` are broadcast against each other.

You can learn more about **broadcasting** [**here**](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#broadcasting) or even better [**here**](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html?highlight=broadcasting#numpy.doc.broadcasting).

Comment: This can be simplified even further using `a.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)` to keep the singleton column dimension, which you can then broadcast along without having to use `np.newaxis`.

Comment: what if any of the row_sums is zero?

Comment: @asdf ...well in that case normalizing by the row sum doesn't really make much sense!

Comment: This is the correct answer for the question as stated above - but if a normalization in the usual sense is desired, use `np.linalg.norm` instead of `a.sum`!

Comment: is this preferred to `row_sums.reshape(3,1)` ?

Comment: It's not as robust since the row sum may be 0.

Comment: If a vector is normalized, it should have a unit norm, using a / row_sums[:, numpy.newaxis] really doesn't guarantee a unit norm.

Comment: @XY.W There are many definitions of "unit norm", take a look at the ord argument to [numpy's norm function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html). Ord 1 norms are often useful and the OP asked specifically about normalizing with respect to this norm, but you can of course replace the denominator with the most appropriate norm for your application.

Comment: Is this the same as MinMaxNorm or what is the name of this normalization?

Comment: This is equivalent to `new_matrix = a / row_sums[:, None]`, as `None` can be used as a shorthand for `np.newaxis`.

Answer (score 134):

Scikit-learn offers a function [`normalize()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html) that lets you apply various normalizations. The "make it sum to 1" is called L1-norm. Therefore:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

matrix = numpy.arange(0,27,3).reshape(3,3).astype(numpy.float64)
# array([[  0.,   3.,   6.],
#        [  9.,  12.,  15.],
#        [ 18.,  21.,  24.]])

normed_matrix = normalize(matrix, axis=1, norm='l1')
# [[ 0.          0.33333333  0.66666667]
#  [ 0.25        0.33333333  0.41666667]
#  [ 0.28571429  0.33333333  0.38095238]]
```

Now your rows will sum to 1.

Comment: This also has the advantage that it works on sparse arrays that would not fit into memory as dense arrays.

Answer (score 11):

I think this should work,

```
a = numpy.arange(0,27.,3).reshape(3,3)

a /=  a.sum(axis=1)[:,numpy.newaxis]
```

Comment: good.  note the change of dtype to arange, by appending decimal point to 27.

Answer (score 6):

In case you are trying to normalize each row such that its magnitude is one (i.e. a row's unit length is one or the sum of the square of each element in a row is one):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(0,27,3).reshape(3,3)

result = a / np.linalg.norm(a, axis=-1)[:, np.newaxis]
# array([[ 0.        ,  0.4472136 ,  0.89442719],
#        [ 0.42426407,  0.56568542,  0.70710678],
#        [ 0.49153915,  0.57346234,  0.65538554]])
```

Verifying:

```
np.sum( result**2, axis=-1 )
# array([ 1.,  1.,  1.])
```

Comment: Axis doesn't seem to be a parameter to np.linalg.norm (anymore?).

Comment: notably this corresponds to the l2 norm (where as rows summing to 1 corresponds to the l1 norm)

Answer (score 4):

I think you can normalize the row elements sum to 1 by this:
    `new_matrix = a / a.sum(axis=1, keepdims=1)`.
And the column normalization can be done with `new_matrix = a / a.sum(axis=0, keepdims=1)`. Hope this can hep.

Answer (score 2):

You could use built-in numpy function: 
`np.linalg.norm(a, axis = 1, keepdims = True)`

Comment: This computes the norm and does not normalize the matrix

Answer (score 1):

it appears that this also works

```
def normalizeRows(M):
    row_sums = M.sum(axis=1)
    return M / row_sums
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use matrix transposition:

```
(a.T / row_sums).T
```

Comment: this answer is incomplete without how you computed `row_sums`

Comment: It is in the original question: `row_sums = a.sum(axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more possible way using `reshape`:

```
a_norm = (a/a.sum(axis=1).reshape(-1,1)).round(3)
print(a_norm)
```

Or using `None` works too:

```
a_norm = (a/a.sum(axis=1)[:,None]).round(3)
print(a_norm)
```

**Output**:

```
array([[0.   , 0.333, 0.667],
       [0.25 , 0.333, 0.417],
       [0.286, 0.333, 0.381]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
a = a / np.linalg.norm(a, ord = 2, axis = 0, keepdims = True)
```

Due to the broadcasting, it will work as intended.

Answer (score -1):

Or using lambda function, like

```
>>> vec = np.arange(0,27,3).reshape(3,3)
>>> import numpy as np
>>> norm_vec = map(lambda row: row/np.linalg.norm(row), vec)
```

each vector of vec will have a unit norm.

Comment: is this using python's `map`? won't builtin numpy functions be much faster?

Answer (score -1):

We can achieve the same effect by premultiplying with the diagonal matrix whose main diagonal is the reciprocal of the row sums.

```py
A = np.diag(A.sum(1)**-1) @ A
```

Comment: too inefficient. you turned a simple sum over all elements into a big (sparse) matrix multiplication

Comment: @qwr The original poster did not ask for a more efficient version, only a less "verbose" one.