# Row-wise scaling with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array H of dimension MxN, and an array A of dimension M . I want to scale H rows with array A. I do it this way, taking advantage of element-wise behaviour of Numpy

```
H = numpy.swapaxes(H, 0, 1)
H /= A
H = numpy.swapaxes(H, 0, 1)
```

It works, but the two swapaxes operations are not very elegant, and I feel there is a more elegant and consise way to achieve the result, without creating temporaries. Would you tell me how ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to normalize a 2-dimensional numpy array in python less verbose?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904694/how-to-normalize-a-2-dimensional-numpy-array-in-python-less-verbose)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can simply use `H/A[:,None]`:

```
In [71]: (H.swapaxes(0, 1) / A).swapaxes(0, 1)
Out[71]: 
array([[  8.91065496e-01,  -1.30548362e-01,   1.70357901e+00],
       [  5.06027691e-02,   3.59913305e-01,  -4.27484490e-03],
       [  4.72868136e-01,   2.04351398e+00,   2.67527572e+00],
       [  7.87239835e+00,  -2.13484271e+02,  -2.44764975e+02]])

In [72]: H/A[:,None]
Out[72]: 
array([[  8.91065496e-01,  -1.30548362e-01,   1.70357901e+00],
       [  5.06027691e-02,   3.59913305e-01,  -4.27484490e-03],
       [  4.72868136e-01,   2.04351398e+00,   2.67527572e+00],
       [  7.87239835e+00,  -2.13484271e+02,  -2.44764975e+02]])
```

because `None` (or `newaxis`) extends `A` in dimension [(example link)](http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#newaxis):

```
In [73]: A
Out[73]: array([ 1.1845468 ,  1.30376536, -0.44912446,  0.04675434])

In [74]: A[:,None]
Out[74]: 
array([[ 1.1845468 ],
       [ 1.30376536],
       [-0.44912446],
       [ 0.04675434]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to reshape `A` so that it will broad cast properly:

```
A = A.reshape((-1, 1))
```

so:

```
In [21]: M
Out[21]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20]])


In [22]: A
Out[22]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])


In [23]: M / A.reshape((-1, 1))
Out[23]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2]])
```