# Python: Create a list (at N length) of all possible proportions of 1 incremented by d decimal points

Tags: python

I want to make a list of floats of `N` length whose total sum is always 1 and each float is incremented by `d` amount.

For example, let `N = 4` and `d = 0.01`:

The desired outcome would be like so:

```
[0.90, 0.02, 0.03, 0.05]
[0.89, 0.02, 0.03, 0.06]
....
# And continues until all possible sums of 1 with the above settings is reached.
# An individual value CAN NOT = 0
```

I'm trying to think of some logic for this but I need some help. Previously I had asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909547/how-to-create-l-lists-of-n-non-zero-random-decimals-where-each-list-sums-to-1-0/31910483#31910483) of similar nature, but uses random numbers instead of all possible combinations.

Comment: "and each float is incremented by d amount" is not clear to me. Are you saying `d` is the number of max decimal points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `itertools` makes this pretty easy:

```
from itertools import permutations, ifilter

N = 4
d = 0.01
D = int(1/d)   


perms = ifilter(lambda x: sum(x) < D, permutations(range(1,D-1), N-1))
tuples = []
for i in perms:
    tuples.append(i + (D-sum(i),))

mylist = [ [ i*d for i in eachtuple ] for eachtuple in tuples ]

print mylist
```

I had assumed that `d` will be 10^(-n) for some integer `n`, but this would work for anything with an integer reciprocal (0.05 and 0.2 should work, but not 0.03).

Floats being floats, you get some floating-point errors, which you could control with an appropriate `round` inside that nested list comprehension.