# Normalize spacy nlp vectors

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, spacy, normalize

I am working with an nlp model where I'd like to normalize the `nlp.vocab.vectors`. From the documentation about [spacy vectors](https://spacy.io/api/vectors) it states that it's an `numpy ndarray`.

I've googled a fair bit about normalizing numpy arrays as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904694/how-to-normalize-a-2-dimensional-numpy-array-in-python-less-verbose), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030391/how-to-normalize-a-numpy-array-to-a-unit-vector) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-normalize-an-numpy-array-so-the-values-range-exactly-between-0-and-1/).

As such I tried the following 3 approaches;

```
import spacy
import numpy as np
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

matrix = nlp.vocab.vectors # Shape (514157, 300)

# Approach 1
matrix_norm1 = matrix/np.linalg.norm(matrix) 
print(matrix_norm1.shape) # Shape (514157,)

# Approach 2
#matrix_norm2 = matrix / np.sqrt(np.sum(matrix**2))
## Results in TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'spacy.vectors.Vectors' and 'int'

# Approach 3
matrix_norm3 = matrix / (np.mean(matrix) - np.std(matrix))
print(matrix_norm3.shape) # => Shape (514157,)
```

The two approaches that returns a result does so but it doesn't retain the dimensions (514157, 300). Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

`nlp.vocab.vectors` is a `Vectors` object. The numpy array is stored in `nlp.vocab.vectors.data`. See: https://spacy.io/api/vectors

Comment: So how can I normalize the `nlp.vocab.vectors`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do? It's fine if you're just extracting the vectors for use elsewhere, but if you modify the vector table in `nlp.vocab.vectors.data` it will break all of the statistical components in the `en_core_web_lg` pipeline.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve what they did [here](https://aclanthology.org/N13-1090.pdf) in section 5

Comment: You can extract the whole in the vector table into word2vec format as shown here: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/6061#discussioncomment-189609. Then you can work with the vector table however you'd like.